# How to center image with width in ion-card

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to center my image in ion-card. I am using width to small the image so thats why its causing problem to center image.

My html code.

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-card class="no-shadow">
            <ion-grid  class="ion-no-padding">
              <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center" >
                <ion-col size="6" >
                  <ion-card class="card-img">
                      <img src="../../assets/imgs/cat-icon.png" >
                      <div><h4>Programming</h4></div>
                  </ion-card>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

.scss

```
ion-content{
    --ion-background-color:  #202849 !important;
}


.no-shadow{
box-shadow: none !important;
}


ion-row{
    ion-card{
    text-align:center;
    width:100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important; // I also dont think important is neccesary
    img{
        width:90px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
}
}
```

Its showing image on left side. I need to show in center here is the image of output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
<ion-card>
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
      <img alt="image" src="assets/logo.png" />
  </div>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

HTML code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card class="no-shadow">
    <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
      <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center">
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-card class="card-img">
            <img src="assets/shapes.svg">
            <div>
              <h4>Programming</h4>
            </div>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-card class="card-img">
            <img src="assets/shapes.svg">
            <div>
              <h5>Programming</h5>
            </div>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-content {
  --ion-background-color: #202849 !important;
}

.no-shadow {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

ion-row {
  ion-card {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px;
    img {
      width: 90px;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }
  }
}
```

and !important is not required  as you changing in page level without important it will work.